# Flutter Cubit Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

For retrieve items from FireStore and for pick image i am using cubit.

Cubit:

```
class ItemCubit extends Cubit<ItemState> {
  ItemCubit(this._dataBase)
      : super(ItemInitial());
  final DataBase _dataBase;
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  Future<void> pickItemImg() async {
    final currentTempImg =
        await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(outputType: ImageType.bytes);
    emit(ItemImgPicked(currentTempImg));
  }

  Future getItem() async {
    streamSubscription = _dataBase.getItem().listen((data) {
      emit(ItemLoaded(data));
    });
  }
}
```

State:

```
@immutable
abstract class ItemState {}

class ItemLoaded extends ItemState {
  final List<Item> item;

  ItemLoaded(this.item);
}

class ItemImgPicked extends ItemState {
  final Uint8List currentTempImg;

  ItemImgPicked(this.currentTempImg);
}
```

Page with blocbuilders

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 400,
                    child: OutlineButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        context.bloc<ItemCubit>().pickProductImg();
                      },
                      child: BlocBuilder<ItemCubit, ItemState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          if (state is ItemImgPicked) {
                            return Image.memory(state.currentTempImg);
                          } else {
                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Text('add'),
          ),
          BlocBuilder<ItemCubit, ItemState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is ItemLoaded) {
                return Column(
                  children: state.item.map(
                    (item) {
                      return Text(item.name);
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                );
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Issue is when on show dialog I picked image, the picked image is displayed, but at the same time on main page blocbuilder for item list return `CircularProgressIndicator`. if I use hot reload at this time,  after it shows me the list of item. It looks like the state for picked image replace state for item list. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your main page bloc builder listens for `ItemLoaded` which you never emit as far as I can tell. You can put a breakpoint into that line, it should not get hit.

That said, please treat your `async` functions better, you missed to await some futures, that might not be your problem now, but it will become a problem sooner or later.